# cpp thread program can't run without -fprofile-arcs

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, compiler-construction

**this is an bug from ubuntu 13.10 and g++ 4.8, so i closed this question.**

```
within -Wl,--no-as-needed.
```

there's something wrong on my head.
i got some code like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    {
        std::thread t1([&]{ std::cout << "hello " << std::endl; });
        t1.join();        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and here is my compile command:

```
g++ -std=c++0x -lpthread test.cpp
```

*ps: i have change my link order for all kind of order.*

it works on g++ 4.7 and ubuntu 13.04
but it throw an system_error on  g++ 4.8.1 and ubuntu 12.10

until i compile with **-fprofile-arcs** it works well.

just bellow:

```
g++ test.cpp -std=c++0x -fprofile-arcs -pthread
a.out
hello

g++ test.cpp -std=c++0x  -pthread
a.out
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
```

what():  Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not permitted

Comment: does it fail at compile or linking?

Comment: suppose is linking, cause the error happend on running

Comment: Works fine when compiled as `g++ -std=c++0x test.cpp -lpthread`.  Throws "operation not permitted" system exception when compiled as `g++ -std=c++0x -lpthread test.cpp`

Comment: still "operation not permitted"

Comment: You need to use the compiler flag `-pthred` (not link to `libpthread` with `-lpthread`).

Comment: is the same situation, i says: if i compile with -fprofile-arcs, then it work well

Comment: If you're actually compiling it with GCC 4.8, how are you using "-std=c++0x" and not "-std=c++11"?

Answer (score 0):

Just span up a Ubuntu 12.10 virtual machine

```
osmith@ubuntu1210 ~/src $ g++-4.8 --version
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.10) 4.8.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

And compiled with this command line:

```
osmith@ubuntu1210 ~/src $ g++-4.8 -std=c++11 -o test.exe test.cpp -pthread -lpthread
osmith@ubuntu1210 ~/src $ ./test.exe
hello
```

Comment: yes, it's fine for my ubuntu 13.04 too, but run fialue in 13.10.